# unbound method ... must be called with

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter

Есть основное окно. В этом окне есть кнопка, при нажатии которой открывается новое окно. В этом окне можно выбрать параметры и установить их при нажатии определенной кнопки. Но когда нажимаю на эту кнопку, то происходит ошибка

> unbound method get() must be called with Settings_of_generation
>   instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Вот часть кода:

```
class Settings_of_generation(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self = Tk()
        self.title('Настройки генерации')
        self.maxsize(500, 500)
        self.minsize(500, 500)
        self.geometry('500x500+100+100')

        label_length_scale_of_password = Label(self, text = 'Длина пароля:', font = 'Arial')
        label_length_scale_of_password.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        length_scale_of_password = Scale(self, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 30, from_ = 1, to = 30, tickinterval = 1, resolution = 1)
        length_scale_of_password.place(x = 0, y = 20, width = 500)

        but = Button(self, text = 'get', command = Settings_of_generation.get())
        but.pack()

    def get(self):
        label_length_scale_of_password.configure(text = length_scale_of_password.get())
```

Полный код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

class Settings_of_generation(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self = Tk()
        self.title('Настройки генерации')
        self.maxsize(500, 500)
        self.minsize(500, 500)
        self.geometry('500x500+100+100')

        self.label_length_scale_of_password = Label(self, text = 'Длина пароля:', font = 'Arial')
        self.label_length_scale_of_password.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        self.length_scale_of_password = Scale(self, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 30, from_ = 1, to = 30, tickinterval = 1, resolution = 1)
        self.length_scale_of_password.place(x = 0, y = 20, width = 500)

        but = Button(self, text = 'get', command = self.get())
        print ('succes')
        but.pack()

    def get(self):
        self.label_length_scale_of_password.configure(text = self.length_scale_of_password.get())

root = Tk()
root.title('Генератор пароля')
root.maxsize(500, 300)
root.minsize(500, 300)
root.geometry('500x300+600+200')

generation_settings_button = Button(root, text = 'Настройки генерации', command = Settings_of_generation)
generation_settings_button.place(x = 0, y = 0)

generation_button = Button(root, text = 'Сгенерировать')
generation_button.place(x = 410, y = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Может в последней строке self.length_scale_of_password? Что у вас в эту переменную проиниализировано? Приведите больше кода

Comment: self.length_scale_of‌​_password не подходит. Я так понимаю, что self это второе окно. Оно вызывается нажатием на кнопку "generation_settings_button = Button(root, text = 'Настройки генерации', command = Settings_of_generation)"

Answer (score 1):

**Первое** - ваш метод `get(self)` это метод объекта потому, что вы указали первым параметром `self`, его можно вызвать только у текущего экземпляра объекта, либо передав параметром ссылку на другой объект.

Settings_of_generation.get() - так писать нельзя. Если только передать какой-то объект.
Settings_of_generation().get() - приведет к рекурсии.
self.get() - вероятно то, что вы хотели сделать.
`self.get` - то что вам нужно, так как в документации Tkinter написано, что в параметр command нужно указывать функцию callback, которая будет вызываться каждый раз, когда вы нажимаете на кнопку.

**Второе** - ваша переменная `label_length_scale_of_password` локальная и никак не проинициализирована в вашем классе, а значит это None и вы будите вызывать свой метод `configure(text = length_scale_of_password.get())` у  None. Это приведет к ошибке. Если она по каким-то причинам определена где-то вне класса, тогда проблемы нету.

```
from Tkconstants import HORIZONTAL
from Tkinter import Label, Scale, Button, Tk


class Settings_of_generation(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title('Settings generation')
        root.maxsize(500, 500)
        root.minsize(500, 500)
        root.geometry('500x500+100+100')
        root.after(500, self.update)

        self.label_length_scale_of_password = Label(root, text = 'Password length:', font = 'Arial')
        self.label_length_scale_of_password.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        self.length_scale_of_password = Scale(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 30, from_ = 1, to = 30, tickinterval = 1, resolution = 1)
        self.length_scale_of_password.place(x = 0, y = 20, width = 500)

        but = Button(root, text='get', command=self.get)
        print("success")
        but.pack()

    def get(self):
        self.label_length_scale_of_password.configure(text=self.length_scale_of_password.get())

    def update(self):
        self.root.update()

root = Tk()
Settings_of_generation(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Первое - при использовании self.get() возникает такая ошибка: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python 2.7.12\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "■■■■■■■■.py", line 20, in __init__
    but = Button(self, text = 'get', command = self.get())
  File "C:\Python 2.7.12\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1899, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: get

Comment: Второе - решит ли проблему следующее: вне класса определить переменную и ей присваивать значение "a = length_scale_of_password.get()" ?

Comment: Раньше не работал с Tkinter. Сейчас времени сильно разбираться нету. Допишу ответ тем что получилось. Попробуйте запустить у себя.

Comment: Конкретно в Вашем примере все запускается без ошибок, но изначально в метке нет текста 'Password length:', но есть '1'. При нажатии на кнопку get обновление текста не происходит. Попробовал немного исправить у себя. У меня дальше "but = Button(self, text = 'get', command = self.get())" не идет. Ошибка: AttributeError: get. Извините, конечно, может я немного не понимаю Вашего ответа и из-за этого делаю неправильно. В конце вопроса я прикрепил весь код.

Comment: В документации tkinter написано, что command принимает callback функцию, которая будет вызываться при нажатии. Я поправил ответ. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm